# Cisco AnyConnect says its connected but no network access?

Tags: networking, cisco-vpn-client

I got Cisco AnyConnect for work, and it worked fine until i reinstalled windows 8.1, and then it stopped. Then i upgraded to windows 10 and it still doesnt work.

It says its connected, but i cant ping any computer in my work network. This is only on my pc, when i use another one it works ok.

I tried reinstalling multiple times, disableing firewall, windows defender and it didnt help.

Anyone have an idea what could i do ?

Comment: Did you check if all network adapter (including the virtual ones) are enabled/activated from the control panel?

Comment: @TJJ Yes, there are two and they are both enabled.